# getting JSON Parse error

Tags: coldfusion

I am getting the following error on my browser:

```
Exceptions

11:05:30.030 - Application Exception - in C:\mypath\myfile.cfm : line 14

        JSON parsing failure: Unexpected end of JSON string
```

Where Line #14 is where I am deserializing the JSON like the following:

```
<cfset incomingData = toString(getHttpRequestData().content) />
```

line #14:

```
<cfset djs = DeserializeJSON(incomingData)/>
```

What does the Application Exception means?

The Stacktrace after dumping variable `djs` is as follows:

```
 coldfusion.runtime.JSONUtils$JSONParseOverflowException: JSON parsing failure: Unexpected end of JSON string at coldfusion.runtime.JSONUtils$ParserState.currentChar(JSONUtils.java:1835) at coldfusion.runtime.JSONUtils.parseObject(JSONUtils.java:949) at coldfusion.runtime.JSONUtils.parseJSON(JSONUtils.java:922) at coldfusion.runtime.JSONUtils.deserializeJSON(JSONUtils.java:162) at coldfusion.runtime.CFPage.DeserializeJSON(CFPage.java:6723) at cfgetIncoming2ecfm1847112669.runPage(C:\Websites\ebmdevii\Event-Based-Messaging\public\response\email\getIncoming.cfm:14) at coldfusion.runtime.CfJspPage.invoke(CfJspPage.java:231) at coldfusion.tagext.lang.IncludeTag.doStartTag(IncludeTag.java:416) at coldfusion.filter.CfincludeFilter.invoke(CfincludeFilter.java:65) at coldfusion.filter.ApplicationFilter.invoke(ApplicationFilter.java:381) at coldfusion.filter.RequestMonitorFilter.invoke(RequestMonitorFilter.java:48) at coldfusion.filter.MonitoringFilter.invoke(MonitoringFilter.java:40) at coldfusion.filter.PathFilter.invoke(PathFilter.java:94) at coldfusion.filter.ExceptionFilter.invoke(ExceptionFilter.java:70) at coldfusion.filter.BrowserDebugFilter.invoke(BrowserDebugFilter.java:79) at coldfusion.filter.ClientScopePersistenceFilter.invoke(ClientScopePersistenceFilter.java:28) at coldfusion.filter.BrowserFilter.invoke(BrowserFilter.java:38) at coldfusion.filter.NoCacheFilter.invoke(NoCacheFilter.java:46) at coldfusion.filter.GlobalsFilter.invoke(GlobalsFilter.java:38) at coldfusion.filter.DatasourceFilter.invoke(DatasourceFilter.java:22) at coldfusion.filter.CachingFilter.invoke(CachingFilter.java:62) at coldfusion.CfmServlet.service(CfmServlet.java:200) at coldfusion.bootstrap.BootstrapServlet.service(BootstrapServlet.java:89) at jrun.servlet.FilterChain.doFilter(FilterChain.java:86) at coldfusion.monitor.event.MonitoringServletFilter.doFilter(MonitoringServletFilter.java:42) at coldfusion.bootstrap.BootstrapFilter.doFilter(BootstrapFilter.java:46) at jrun.servlet.FilterChain.doFilter(FilterChain.java:94) at jrun.servlet.FilterChain.service(FilterChain.java:101) at jrun.servlet.ServletInvoker.invoke(ServletInvoker.java:106) at jrun.servlet.JRunInvokerChain.invokeNext(JRunInvokerChain.java:42) at jrun.servlet.JRunRequestDispatcher.invoke(JRunRequestDispatcher.java:286) at jrun.servlet.ServletEngineService.dispatch(ServletEngineService.java:543) at jrun.servlet.jrpp.JRunProxyService.invokeRunnable(JRunProxyService.java:203) at jrunx.scheduler.ThreadPool$DownstreamMetrics.invokeRunnable(ThreadPool.java:320) at jrunx.scheduler.ThreadPool$ThreadThrottle.invokeRunnable(ThreadPool.java:428) at jrunx.scheduler.ThreadPool$UpstreamMetrics.invokeRunnable(ThreadPool.java:266) at jrunx.scheduler.WorkerThread.run(WorkerThread.java:66)
```

Note: The same file when I run on different Coldfusion 8 Server located at different IP doesn't throw any error.

Comment: What version of Coldfusion is it?

Comment: Coldfusion 9 where I am getting error and it's Coldfusion 8 where I am not getting any error.

Comment: Try doing a `cfdump` of `toString(getHttpRequestData().content)` to see what the page content actually is.

Comment: @ScottStroz When I dump `incomingData` , I get `[empty string]` as my output.

Comment: There you go, an empty string is not valid JSON.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error message is very clear: `JSON parsing failure: Unexpected end of JSON string`

You're trying to parse a string as JSON, and the string *isn't* JSON.

Put a try/catch around the erroring line, and in the catch dump out the string you're trying to deserialise. You will undoubtedly see that the string *isn't* JSON. Hence the error saying it can't be parsed as such.

Comment: When I dump `incomingData` , I get ` [empty string] ` as my output.

Comment: Actually I am having the same issue, accept I get [empty string] {"chatid":""}

Comment: @CharlesRobertson it's hard to say much about your situation without seeing a repro case for it. I suggest you raise a new question, if you think your situation is discrete from this one.

Comment: Thanks Adam. I managed to sort it [see below]. You were correct, the JSON string was invalid, as it had an [empty string], directly preceding the JSON part, which caused the DeserializeJson() method to fail. All, I did was remove empty spaces before & after the JSON string. Actually, Trim() wasn't enough, hence my use of REReplaceNoCase(). I would add that the POST request was sent using the Angular 4, in-built, Observable, "http()"...

Comment: Ah sounds like it was a tab or something, not a space, eh? Anyway: glad you got it sorted.

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me:

```
<cfset requestBody = toString(getHttpRequestData().content)>
<cfset requestBody = REReplaceNoCase(requestBody,"[\s+]"," ","ALL")>
<cfset requestBody = Trim(requestBody)>
<cftry>
<cfset requestBody = DeserializeJSON(requestBody)>
<cfcatch>
<cfdump var="#requestBody#" />
</cfcatch>
</cftry>
```